# How can I set a url request like this? 'baseurl/frontname/index.php?/param'

Tags: url

I need to make an action method that will receive a parameter in the url, perform a search and return an array. Anyway, that's not the problem. My problem is that I want a url like 'baseurl/frontname/param'. I don't know how to do this. I've already seem a Magento site performimg same operation with a url like 'baseurl/frontname/index.php?/param'. It's good for me too.

Can someone help me to realize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a module and a controller that performs the search.
If so, you can get the url like this:

```
 Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action', array('param_name1'=>'value1', 'param_name2'=>'value2', ....));
```

This will generate something like this:

```
 BASE_URL/module/controller/action/param_name1/value1/param_name2/value2/...
```

If you want the params to be in the query string do this:

```
Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action', array('_query'=>'param_name1=value1&param_name2=value2'));
```

This will generate:

```
BASE_URL/module/controller/action?param_name1=value1&param_name2=value2
```

If you don't want the controller name and action name in the url, then name your controller `IndexController` and your action `indexAction` and get the url like this:

```
Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'module', '_query'=>'param_name1=value1&param_name2=value2'))
```

This will generate

```
 BASE_URL/module?param_name1=value1&param_name2=value2
```